# How to regularize the intercept with glmnet

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression, glmnet, regularized

I know that glmnet does not regularize the intercept by default, but I would like to do it anyway. I was taking a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282585/does-r-glmnet-regularize-on-intercept) and tried to do what whuber suggested (adding a constant variable and turning the parameter `intercept` to `FALSE`) , but as a result glmnet is not fitting the added constant as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(glmnet)

X <-
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(intercept = 1) %>%
  select(-c(mpg)) %>%
  as.matrix()

y <-
  mtcars %>%
  select(mpg) %>%
  as.matrix()

model <- glmnet(X, y, intercept = FALSE, alpha = 0, lambda = 0)

coef(model)
```

Comment: Post an example that can be run.

Comment: Mean-correct your data. Then the intercept will be perfectly regularized to zero.

Comment: @HongOoi Can you post an example? What do you mean by "perfectly regularized"?